# DE19817372C1 date order incorrect in Google Patents?

Tags: google-patents, date, priority-date

Per Google Patents, the order of dates for patent [DE19817372C1](https://patents.google.com/patent/DE19817372C1/en) appears incorrect.

Per the site, the patent expired on April 18th 1998 (Fee Related), but lists a grant date of Oct 7th, 1999.

Looking at the legal events listed on the page on Google Patents, a series of different dates show up:

[image]

What's going on here? Is it nothing more than data import that got messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date shown on google patents on the right side next to the patent number where it says

date - number - status

is the application/filing/publication date for the number next to it, not the date of the status at the right side.

So the application was filed 1998 and is **now** deemed withdrawn/lapsed.